# Remove border from JButton

Tags: java, swing, border, jbutton

I would have a problem with the edges of my `jbutton`. In practice, in the code below I inserted a button that should not have edges but instead appear as in the photo below.

```java
        JButton btnRes = new JButton();
        btnRes.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnRes.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnRes.setOpaque(false);
        btnRes.setBorder(null);
        btnRes.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource(image1)));
        btnRes.setPressedIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource(image2)));
        btnRes.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource(image3)));
        btnRes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            //TODO
            }
        });
        btnRes.setBounds(496, 342, 138, 48);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnRes);
```

and this is the result:

[Image of this JButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFgYE.png)

The border is however visible, how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see the border that is added to the button because it is selected. Try:

```
btnRes.setFocusPainted(false);
```